# Importing previously used strings into a new method

Tags: java, string, selenium, jpanel, desktop

I have a string (initialized in my main method) that I want to use in a new JFrame window method. I have the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='pagecontainer']/section/ul/li[1]/a"));
String linkLocation = link.getAttribute("href");
}
```

for my main method and the following code for a JButton in my JPanel

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
desk.browse(new URI(linkLocation));
}
```

How do I get this to work?

Comment: Do you have access to `JButton` in same place you have fetched `linkLocation`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some thing like this maybe help you :

```
public String LinkLocation(){
    WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='pagecontainer']/section/ul/li[1]/a"));
    String linkLocation = link.getAttribute("href");
    return linkLocation;
    }

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
desk.browse(new URI(LinkLocation()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your `String` outside of `main`:

```
public String linkLocation = " ";
public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='pagecontainer']/section/ul/li[1]/a"));
    linkLocation = link.getAttribute("href");
}
```

You can now reference `linkLocation` from other places. Simply typing `linkLocation` should work if your new method is in the same class, otherwise use `classname.linkLocation`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have access to `JButton` in same place you have fetched `linkLocation`, you give it a try `JButton.setActionCommand()`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   // ...
   String linkLocation = link.getAttribute("href");
   jButton.setActionCommand(linkLocation);
   // ..
}
```

And now you can get it using, as per your post that below is button handler:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  desk.browse(new URI(e.getActionCommand()));
}
```